# How to find array elements with Mongoose?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have an array as a subdocument in the Mongoose model defined as follows:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = Schema({
    author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' },
    pages: [{
        number: Number, 
        type: { type: String, enum: ['boring', 'fun']},
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', schema);
```

Now I want to get the total number of `'fun'` pages across all books by a certain author. Many similar questions (and answers) I found discuss how to find `Book`s with fun pages in this scenario, however I want to get an array of all fun pages, or at least the length of that array, but if possible I would like to get the array itself. How can I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: Try (untested, will add as an answer if correct):

    Book.aggregate(
    
        { $unwind: "$pages" },
    
        { $group: {
            _id: "$pages.type",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }}
    )

Comment: @nadavvadan Thanks! It seems like it's working. But I just realized I needed one more filtering, instead of all books, I need to select from books only by a certain author. If it won't be much to ask, can you please add that too? :) Thanks again,

Comment: try this: Book.aggregate( {$match: {author: ObjectId("12-bytes-of-hex")} }, { $unwind: "$pages" }, { $group: { _id: "$pages.type", count: { $sum: 1 } }} )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that, aside from syntax, this is pretty self-explanatory:

```
Book.aggregate(

    { 
        $match: {
            author: ObjectId("12-bytes-of-hex")
        }
     },

    { $unwind: "$pages" },

    { $group: {
        _id: "$pages.type",
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
)
```

Comment: I don't understand btw, how does this filter pages according to `type=='fun'`?

Comment: It doesn't do exactly that; it groups the pages by page type, and counts each group. You could also use mongo׳s mapReduce framework to get just the page counts for the 'fun' page type, but I believe the above solution is simpler.